# Rendering Multiple Buttons in a View react native programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Want to render buttons Based upon the json 
    {
        "ActionType" : [{
         "Field" : "Button",
         "FieldText" : "No",
         "FieldAction" : "this.getCellNumber('no')",
         "style":""
    },{
          "Field" : "Button",
          "FieldText" : "No",
          "FieldAction" : "this.getCellNumber('yes')",
          "style":""
     }]
    }

How can I loop it in a render function to get number of buttons in a view

```
render(){
  return(

        <View style={this.styles.ButtonValContainer}>

        </View>
);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in react you can easily collect an array of elements for rendering.

```
const buttons = [
    {
      text: 'button one',
      action: () => console.log('pressed button one'),
    }, 
    {
      text: 'button two',
      action: () => console.log('pressed button two')            
    }
];
```

....

```
// react class definition

// ...
// assuming `Button` is a defined class in scope.

render() {
  const renderedButtons =  buttons.map(b => {
    return <Button key={b.text} text={b.text} onPress={b.action} />;
  });

  return (
    <View>
     {renderedButtons}
    </View>
  )
}
```

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks @mason505 , this helps.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the button array-button two is named 'test' whereas i think it should be 'text'.

Comment: you are correct. I'll will update the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through a list and return a component in the callback. The only requirement is that the returned component has an `key` attribute, which is used by React internally when rerendering (so that it knows what to remove/shift/update etc)

```
render() {
  return(
    <Wrapper>
      {items.forEach(function(item) {
        return (
          <View style={this.styles.ButtonValContainer} key={'UNIQUE_KEY_HERE'}>
            ...
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Here's some more info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Comment: Getting this error:  ExceptionsManager.js:61 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.