# Rendering multiple buttons with different onPress React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render 3 buttons with different text and action onPress(). 
I've found this solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090316/rendering-multiple-buttons-in-a-view-react-native-programmatically) but it didn't work for me.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    isModalVisible: false
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
  };

  testfunc = () => {
    console.log("this f***ng WORKS");
  };

  renderButtons = () => {
    const buttons = [
      {
        title: "I have no clear direction",
        action: () => console.log("this WORKS")
      },
      { title: "I have some idea of what i want", action: () => this.testfunc },
      { title: "I know exactly what i want", action: this.toggleModal }
    ];

    buttons[0].action();
    buttons[1].action;
    buttons[2].action;

    return buttons.map((i, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20, width: "100%" }} key={index}>
          <OnboardingButton
            title={i.title}
            loading={this.state.loading}
            onPress={() => i.action}
          />
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
}
```

I used console.log() just for testing. 
As output when this screen is rendered I'm getting this:

```js
this WORKS
```

When I click on any button nothing happens.

Comment: @Tholle No, still nothing happens when I click on buttons

Comment: @Tholle It actually worked and I tried it before. The problem was that `onPress()` was overridden in `<OnboardingButton>`. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

By writing `onPress={() => i.action}` you are creating a new inlined function that returns the `action` function of that button. The `action` for your second button is also creating a new function that returns the `this.testfunc` function.

Just give a reference to the function instead and it will work as expected.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    isModalVisible: false
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
  };

  testfunc = () => {
    console.log("this f***ng WORKS");
  };

  renderButtons = () => {
    const buttons = [
      {
        title: "I have no clear direction",
        action: () => console.log("this WORKS")
      },
      { title: "I have some idea of what i want", action: this.testfunc },
      { title: "I know exactly what i want", action: this.toggleModal }
    ];

    return buttons.map((i, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20, width: "100%" }} key={index}>
          <OnboardingButton
            title={i.title}
            loading={this.state.loading}
            onPress={i.action}
          />
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```